# Validating controls in ListView insert/edit templates

Tags: asp.net, validation, listview

I added a RequiredFieldValidator to my InsertItemTemplate, and it seems to be working fine.  The problem I am having, however, is that now I cannot do anything else in the ListView (like edit or delete items) UNLESS the required field has a value.  Is there some way I can manually do the validation when the user clicks the 'Insert' button on the InsertItemTemplate, or some other little trick I can perform so the user doesn't have to first type in a value just to delete something else in the list?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 
set the CausesValidation property to false on the controls you don't want them to trigger the validation.

Answer (score 4):

A_Nablsi,

Please provide the code for your solution to turn the Insert New validation controls off when in Edit/Update mode or turn Edit/Update validation controls off when both the Edit and Insert Rows are active at the same time. This code using your notional solution fails with a null reference to the updateButton.

```
LinkButton updateButton = LVTasks.EditItem.FindControl("UpdateButtonTask") as LinkButton;
updateButton.CausesValidation = false;
```

**The solution that works** is adding **Validation Groups**.

Include ValidationGroup="myVGEdit" with your Validator Control(s) in the EditItemTemplate and your Update button.

Include ValidationGroup="myVGInsert" with your Validator Control(s) in the InsertItemTemplate and your Insert button.

```
<asp:ListView ID="LVTasks" runat="server" 
    DataKeyNames="IDTask" 
    DataSourceID="LDS_LVTasks" 

    InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" 

    oniteminserting="LVTasks_ItemInserting" 
    onitemupdating="LVTasks_ItemUpdating" 
    onitemcommand="LVTasks_ItemCommand"  
    >

    <EditItemTemplate> 
       <asp:TextBox ID="TaskUpdateTextBox" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Bind("Task") %>' 
            TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="1" Font-Bold="true" Width="300px"
        />

       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="Please Set Task title"
            ControlToValidate="TaskUpdateTextBox"

            ValidationGroup="myVGUpdate"
        />

                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
                CommandArgument='<%#Eval("IDTask") %>' 
                CommandName="Cancel" 
                CausesValidation="False"          
                ToolTip="Cancel - Abort - No Changes"><div class="Cancel"></div></asp:LinkButton>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButtonTask" runat="server" 
                CommandArgument='<%#Eval("IDTask") %>' 
                CommandName="Update" 

                CausesValidation="True"

                ValidationGroup="myVGEdit"

                ToolTip="Save Changes - Update"><div class="Update" ></div></asp:LinkButton>
    </EditItemTemplate> 

    <InsertItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="TaskInsertTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Task") %>' 
            TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="1" Font-Bold="true" Width="300px"
        />

       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="Please Set Task title"
            ControlToValidate="TaskInsertTextBox"

            ValidationGroup="myVGInsert"
        />

       <asp:LinkButton ID="CancelButton" runat="server" 
                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("IDTask") %>' 
                    CommandName="Cancel" 
                    CausesValidation="False"><div class="Clear" ></div></asp:LinkButton>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButtonTask" runat="server" 
                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("IDTask") %>' 
                    CommandName="Insert" 
                    CausesValidation="true"

                    ValidationGroup="myVGInsert"

                    ><div class="Insert" ></div></asp:LinkButton>

    </InsertItemTemplate>
```

Comment: This should be accepted as answer!

Thank you for finding time to post your answer.
It is exactly what I were looking for.

Comment: This is a little old, but very much appreciated.  I had to programmatically add validation groups to my master page user control save button, and then use different validation groups in each of my formview templates.  Thank you!